# Can't include related User and Network fields in a LoginHistory query?

Tags: soql, query, user, relationships, login-history

I want to include `User.UserName` and `Network.Name` in a `LoginHistory` SOQL query (e.g. `SELECT Id, User.UserName, Network.NetworkName FROM LoginHistory`), but the system doesn't "understand" either relationship.  Can anyone confirm this limitation?  It will be annoying to have to write two more queries for user and network fields.

I tried to run Developer Workbench to examine further but it is not working right now (DNS address could not be found).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like English language, there are more exceptions than rules in Salesforce :) Not being able to do parent reference query on Parent fields sometimes is one of them.

Salesforce typically populates "relationshipName" on reference fields which are traversable. For LoginHistory, `user` object doesn't have that relationship name (as you can see below). So without that, you cannot traverse.

[image]

Since `LoginGeo` has relationship name, you can traverse that using `select LoginGeo.City from loginhistory`.